# Same tab bar on every view

Tags: ios, swift, view, tabbar

I'm trying to create an app with three primary views (maybe even more in the future) that you can always get to from anywhere.

The tab bar controller works great for that, I have 3 icons in the bar for every view. However, when branching off from any of those to other modal views, the tab bar is obviously no longer there.

I got around it by embedding one view in a container, so it is not overlapping the tab bar, but I cannot do the same thing for another view. (fx. on the screenshot you can see Zastavky Table View, I would like to be able to get to another view by clicking cell in this one, yet still have a tabbar on the bottom)

**Screenshot of storyboard**: 
[image]
Do you guys have any idea how this could be done? Is my whole concept wrong here? Thank you very much! :)

Comment: Try making table view controller as the root view controller.When you tap on the cell ,then present the UITabBarcontroller. By this way you are able to show the tabbar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `navigation` with `show` segue.

```
UITabBarController
|--UINavigationController
|   `--UIViewControllerA
|--UINavigationController
|   `--UIViewControllerB
`--UINavigationController
    `--UIViewControllerC
```

This construct may help you.

Comment: Thank you very much, I´ve changed the root view controller to my table view controller, it works now :)